# Get Facebook Link Likes

Tags: facebook

Using the Facebook API with the FQL language, how can I get a list of the users that liked a given URL? I got the URL and want to query Facebook to see how many people and what users liked that URL.

Using PHP or ASP.Net... doesn't matter, just want to know how to write the FQL query.

Answer (score 3):

Sadly this data isn't available. What's possible via the [Link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/link/) Graph API objects and the [link FQL table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/links/) is just retrieving a given instance in which a link was shared by a user.  You can get the count of likes on a user's posting of a link, but this likely isn't what you want.

Discussed this 3-6 months ago with guys at Facebook, and the consensus then was also that getting this data via API is impossible.  As far as I know things haven't changed, and there are some privacy arguments for keeping this data out of the API.

Answer (score 0):

```
'SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id IN (SELECT link_id from link WHERE url = 'YOUR URL HERE' AND owner = 'YOUR USER ID HERE' '
```

[Like FQL Table](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Like_%28FQL%29)

[Link FQL table](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Link_(FQL))

Comment: Not working, i choose that I liked an item but it doesn't get assigned to my name.

Comment: uhm... so strange, could you separate the fql and try to get the object id first, then user that object id in the select like fql? I think it may because the string and int.

Comment: I also posted 2 fql table so that you can look at it. I will try the sql myself soon

Answer (score 0):

In order to access user's likes, the application needs to have `user_likes` permission from the user. After that if you access `http://graph.facebook.com/me/likes` with appropriate access tokens, all the object IDs (including external websites), the current user has liked will be listed.

(this is in reply to bounty question, which seems a bit different from the original question asked on this page)

Comment: I'm sorry may be my question was confusing. What i wanted is to get list of all user_ids who liked something on my external page. For example I have a movie page with a like button and I want to get all facebook user_ids who liked the page.

Answer (score 0):

It's not using FQL but...you can see the most recent 500 users that have like your page by going to: `https://www.facebook.com/browse/?type=page_fans&page_id={id}` but you would have to scrape this to get the information and it won't work for more people besides the most recent 500.  Here's the gotcha, you've gotta be an admin of the page_id to see it.

Answer (score 0):

You can only get the fans of pages that you are an administrator for. So you have to provide an access token with your request associated with an admin account of the page you are trying to get the fans.

Facebook's FQL documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page/ tells you how to do it. Run the example `SELECT name, fan_count FROM page WHERE page_id = 19292868552` and replace the page_id number with your page's id number and it will return the page name and the fan count.